# Python String, List and Tuple behave differently

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator, tuples

Please help me to understand the different outputs when I use string, list and tuples as an iterator in a for loop.
In Python 2.7 interactive prompt, I am running below sequence of commands:

```
>>> for x in 'spam':
...     print x*2
...
```

**Output**:
ss
pp
aa
mm

```
>>> for x in ['spam']:
...     print x*2
...
```

**Output:**
 spamspam

```
>>> for x in ('spam'):
...     print x*2
...
```

**Output:**
ss
pp
aa
mm

```
>>> for x in ('spam',):
...     print x*2
...
```

**Output:**
spamspam

```
>>> for x in tuple('spam'):
...     print x*2
...
```

**Output:**
ss
pp
aa
mm

Comment: `'spam' == ('spam')` / `tuple('spam') == ('s', 'p', 'a', 'm')`

Comment: `in ('spam')` is equal `in 'spam'` which is treated as `in ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']`.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for strings, lists, and tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question for beginners because it helps in understanding Python syntax. Below is my explanation.

1. `for x in 'spam': ...`

Here input is a `str` that supports the iterator protocol. So when we run a for loop on it each character will be returned one at a time.

2. `for x in ['spam']: ...`

Here a `list` of single item is created from a `str`. So we iterate through the loop only once.

3. `for x in ('spam'): ...`

You may be misled to think that you are creating a `tuple` out of a `str`. In fact, `()` is nothing more than a normal parentheses. If the intention is to create a tuple with a single item, then the correct syntax is shown in the next example. For this example, you are passing a `str` object to the for loop and it will iterate character by character.

4. `for x in ('spam',): ...`

Comma is important. It helps in telling interpreter to create a single-item `tuple`. Since there's only one item in the `tuple`, we iterate through the loop only once.

5. `for x in tuple('spam'): ...`

This is really creating a `tuple` of items from a `str`. Since we iterate through a `str` one character at a time, we end up with a tuple of many items, each item being a single character. In fact, `list('spam')` will also behave this way and not like `['spam']`.

Answer (score 1):

**So your first example**:

Remember strings don't actually exist in computers, they're actually arrays/lists - so in reality `"spam"` to the computer means `['s', 'p', 'a', 'n']`

**Second example**:

Since there is only one item in the list, it will perform a `for loop` for how many items are in such list

**third example**:

a tulip with no other item than itself is treated as an unchangeable string.

**Fourth example**:
  a tulip with multiple entries is treated more like an unchangeable list, keeping it's order and values.

I hope this helped and don't be shy to change the answer if anyone knows better.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'spam' or ('spam') are both string so you are iterating on each char
2. ['spam'] is a list of on string so iterate on it will output a single string the same is for ('spam',)
3. tuple('spam') is generating a tuple that consists of chars in the string means ('s','p','a','m') so the output is obvious